# How to solve "Bad url hash" while attempting open post image url?

Tags: facebook, url

i'm trying to open this URL:

https://scontent.fcpq1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t45.1600-4/296261150_23851112299400356_8151382196790433755_n.png?stp=cp0_dst-jpg_p526x296_q90_spS444

But i'm receiving "Bad Url Hash" error...

I've seen some people saying to remove "special" characters from the url, but I haven't seen anything that could cause this error...

Thanks for attention guys!

Edit: I found the error, when i copy the link from scrapper he miss a importants params, i hope this help anyone! xD

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how you solved this?  Perhaps, even provide it as an answer to your question.